# If S is a set of reals such that between any two distinct elements of the set there is another element of the set, is S dense?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Let S be a set of reals 
such that
between any two distinct elements of the set
there is another element of the set.

Is S dense between its min amd max?

I outlined a proof that
this is true if
there is a real number $0 < r \le 1/2$ such that between any two distinct elements of the set a and b there is a third element c such that
$r \le |(c-a)/(b-a)| \le 1-r$
in my answer to this question:

[How to prove that every real number is the limit of a convergent sequence of rational numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2270058/how-to-prove-that-every-real-number-is-the-limit-of-a-convergent-sequence-of-rat/2270164#2270164)

The proof essentially involves repeated bisection, with the condition involving r ensuring that this converges.

Without the condition involving $r$
(or some condition like it),
this might be false.

I envision starting with the set
${0} \cup \{\frac1{n}| n \in \mathbb{N^+}\}$
and iterating it $\aleph_0$ times,
with the clumping at the left
being more pronounced
at each iteration.

I don't know if this is possible,
or if the set is dense.

Comment: Instead of min and max, you certainly mean inf and sup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  $(0,1) \cup (2,3)$ is a counterexample.  With the condition on $r$ it is true.  Given any $r$ in your range you can find $a$ just below $1$ and $b$ just above $2$ so that your condition on $r$ cannot be satisfied with this set.

Comment: Nice counterexample. I was looking for a set of individual points not intervals.

Comment: You can replace the intervals with dense sets as long as you don't have both endpoints of the empty interval.  For example you could just have the rationals in each interval and add in $1$ or $2$ but not both.  I think this is the structure of all the dense subsets of the reals-sets which are locally dense with gaps in between, but am not sure.